# To get coordinate from gps with Mylocation.getMyLocation() on a not mapacitivity

Tags: android, gps, mapactivity, mylocationoverlay

I am becoming crazy because i must get my position from gps, throught `mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation()` FROM a `ListActivity` AND NOT `MapActivity`. `GetMyLocation` wants context and mapview that i don't have. I tried to take a `mapActivity` but i get Error to runtime `" Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mapView == null "` on `MyLocationOverlay()` constructor . I post my wrong code:

```
public class ListDeals extends ListActivity
{   

private Events[] events;  
private MyLocationOverlay mMyLocationOverlay;//Riferimento al MyLocationOverlay
private GeoPoint myPoint = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  String type = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("type"); //legge cosa c'era scritto nell'intent per avere il dato necessario per fare la query al db

  setContentView(R.layout.list_view_x_deals);
  MapView mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
  mMyLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, MyMapView.mapView);
  myPoint = mMyLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
```

Where MyMapView.mapView is  a "final MapView" created inside the my MapActivity.

Where do i wrong?

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `MapView` stuff if you don't have a `MapView`. Use the [regular GPS api](http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/) to get a `Location` and convert it to a `GeoPoint` if you want it in that format.

Comment: But How can i obtain my current location from LocationManager without MyLocationOverlay?

Comment: Those 2 classes are completely seperate (although the Overlay might use its own LocationManager).